# Cant get .htaccess to work in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a subdirectory called test.mydomain.com where I am hosting a number of static files for test engineers to have access to.

I'm trying to allow directory browsing so that the engineers can FTP files and then browse for those files (e.g. from a mobile device) without having the need for any sort of front-end GUI.

my `.htaccess` file is

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=*
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable
```

but this not working.

Adding an `index.html` file to the subdir folder displays the HTML content so the DNS is all set up correctly.

Site is hosted with names.co.uk - Linux server with Apache.

Comment: Maybe your host does not accept custom htaccess files? Probably ask the support team at names.co.uk.

Comment: I've got a custom htaccess file running at the site root. I just can get it to run at the subdirectory root.
If I move all my files into a subfolder (test.mydomain.com/files) I can browse the directory listing at this location. Just not at the root.

Comment: Have you tried to have only Options +Indexes in the file?

Comment: I have yes. Are there any other htaccess lines I could use to test if things are working. Maybe use it to print something to screen?

Comment: Btw, what does the root htaccess file do? If you have some mod_rewrite you have to set RewriteOptions to none.

Comment: the rootfile contains
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Did it work on your site now?

Comment: I deleted the htaccess file and now i'm able to browse the folder structure as expected. It's just all of a sudden decided to allow access. I hate computers

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not have an index.* in the directory where you want to show the files, Apache checks your htaccess files for what to do. The parent htaccess file has a mod_rewrite condition for when your server is accessed, and here does the rewrite condition what you have made it do. It does not find an index.* file, and it rewrites it instead. So you have to disable mod_rewrite for the subdir.
Put this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteOptions none
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=*
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable
```